# JSON: Retrieving JSON file from another domain

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

After awhile of not using JSON, I'm a little rusty on the possibility of requestiing the data from another domain/web-server.

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  if(!empty($_GET['file'])){
?>
  jsonFile = 'data/<?php echo $_GET['file']; ?>';
<?php
  }
?>
```

Is there a way to do this without using JSONP? I think the way I have my code setup, it queries from a data/ folder. That data folder is also available on the other web server. Any thoughts? All appreciated.

Comment: You will most likely encounter CrossBrowser scripting error with that ... Which will result in an error

Comment: @IamCavic What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need that header here. Presence of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` matters only when you are requesting a resource from another domain via browser. And it's the target server that should return the header not the client. Since you are using PHP you just need to request the resource normally.

Check the [MDN's CORS article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more information.